# Vue.js Child Component not Updating Data in Parent Component

Tags: vue.js

I am using vue components in a Laravel project.

I have taken sample code from https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#usage-with-v-model

I have a child component with an input box:

```
<script>
    export default {
    props: ['modelValue'],
   emits: ['update:modelValue']
}
</script>

<template>
  <input
   :value="modelValue"
   @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
 />
</template>
```

This component is being used in a parent component.

```
 <phone-input v-model="phone"/>  {{phone}}
```

The parent component displays the input box with the initial value of the phone variable. However, the changed value is not reflected in the parent's phone variable ( {{phone}} does not update). Am I missing something? I have cleared the cache, but it did not help.

I tried another variation of the code (from vue.js documentation code) as given here. However, this also does not work.

```
Parent
 <MyComponent v-model:title="bookTitle" />. {{bookTitle}}



<!-- Child Component MyComponent.vue -->
<script>
 export default {
 props: ['title'],
 emits: ['update:title']
 }
</script>

<template>
  <input
   type="text"
   :value="title"
   @input="$emit('update:title', $event.target.value)"
 />
</template>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at following snippet, looks ok:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      phone: "0123456"
    }
  },
})
app.component('phoneInput', { 
  template: `
    <input
      :value="modelValue"
      @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
    />
  `,
  props: ['modelValue'],
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
})

app.mount("#demo")
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
   <phone-input v-model="phone"></phone-input>
   {{ phone }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code works. Even the sample codes given in the vue documentation work. However, the code was not working for me. But, the code suggested by Ifaruki works for me. Do you find anything wrong in the the code that I have posted in my question?

Comment: I have noticed that none of the sample codes are working in my app, which is Laravel 9 with Vue 3. Perhaps, there is something wrong in my app. I will create a fresh laravel app and try two way data binding. Meanwhile, if you or anyone has any suggestions, I shall appreciate receiving them.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    export default {
    props: ['modelValue'],
}
</script>

<template>
  <input
   :value="modelValue"
   @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
 />
</template>
```

You need specially emit `input` to make it work

Comment: I think that ‘input’ is used in vue 2, which has been updated to ‘update:modelValue’ in Vue 3. Since I am using vue 3, this may not work.